# Solve optimization using fmincon MATLAB when objective function is in constraints

Tags: matlab, optimization, minimization

I want to solve: [image]

I use following MATLAB code, but it does not work.

Can someone please guide me?

```
function f=objfun

f=-f;

function [c1,c2,c3]=constraint(x)
a1=1.1; a2=1.1; a3=1.1;
c1=f-log(a1)-log(x(1)/(x(1)+1)); 
c2=f-log(a2)-log(x(2)/(x(2)+1))-log(1-x(1)); 
c3=f-log(a3)-log(1-x(1))-log(1-x(2));


x0=[0.01;0.01]; 
[x,fval]=fmincon('objfun',x0,[],[],[],[],[0;0],[1;1],'constraint')
```

Comment: Your definition of objfun doesn't make any sense to me...

Comment: Does not work means nothing. What specifically is wrong?

Comment: how can I define `obtfun' since it is not function of `x'? Thats the place I am struggling.

Comment: Replace T for x3 and it should make sense. T is just another choice variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to flip the problem around a bit. You are trying to find the point `x` (which is `(l_1,l_2)`) that makes the minimum of the 3 LHS functions the largest. So, you can rewrite your problem as, in pseudocode,

```
maximise, by varying x in [0,1] X [0,1]
       min([log(a1)+log(x(1)/(x(1)+1)) ...
            log(a2)+log(x(2)/(x(2)+1))+log(1-x(1)) ...
            log(a3)+log(1-x(1))+log(1-x(2))])
```

Since Matlab has `fmincon`, rewrite this as a minimisation problem,

```
minimise, by varying x in [0,1] X [0,1]
       max(-[log(a1)+log(x(1)/(x(1)+1)) ...
             log(a2)+log(x(2)/(x(2)+1))+log(1-x(1)) ...
             log(a3)+log(1-x(1))+log(1-x(2))])
```

So the actual code is

```
F=@(x) max(-[log(a1)+log(x(1)/(x(1)+1)) ...
             log(a2)+log(x(2)/(x(2)+1))+log(1-x(1)) ...
             log(a3)+log(1-x(1))+log(1-x(2))])
[L,fval]=fmincon(F,[0.5 0.5])
```

which returns

```
L =
    0.3383    0.6180
fval =
    1.2800
```

Comment: Thanks @David !!! When I run your code, it says `FMINCON requires at least four input arguments.` is something missing in your code?

Comment: That's weird, all I have extra is the line `a1=1.1;a2=1.1;a3=1.1;`.

Comment: You must have a different version of Matlab, I have 2015a here. `fmincon` should take more than 2 arguments, it does contrained optimisation, so it should require constraints I guess. Try this instead: `[L,fval]=fmincon(F,[0.5 0.5],[],[],[],[],[0 0],[1 1])`.

Comment: Thanks @David !!! It really helps, and I actually need this problem for any N number of constraints. I have already tried for three, and it works: `[x,fval]=fmincon(F,[0.5 0.5 0.5],[],[],[],[],[0;0;0],[1;1;1])`. Have a great day !!! BTW do you have any idea of modifying my approach, just curious, but not necessary :)

Comment: Yeah that's the right approach for more L's, for more constraints you only need to change the `F` by adding a new row for the new constraint.

Answer (score 0):

Can also solve this in the [convex optimization package CVX](http://cvxr.com/cvx/) with the following MATLAB code:

```
cvx_begin
 variables T(1);
 variables x1(1);
 variables x2(1);

 maximize(T)
 subject to:
  log(a1) + x1 - log_sum_exp([0, x1]) >= T;
  log(a2) + x2 - log_sum_exp([0, x2]) + log(1 - exp(x1)) >= T;
  log(a3) +  log(1 - exp(x1)) +  log(1 - exp(x2)) >= T;
  x1 <= 0;
  x2 <= 0;
cvx_end
l1 = exp(x1); l2 = exp(x2);
```

To use CVX, each constraint and the objective function has to be written in a way that is proveably convex using CVX's ruleset. Making the substitution `x1 = log(l1)` and `x2 = log(l2)` allows one to do that. Note that: `log_sum_exp([0,x1]) = log(exp(0) + exp(x1)) = log(1 + l1)`

This also returns the answers: l1 = .3383, l2 = .6180, T = -1.2800